# Business Invitation Date only 8 days before Visa Submission

Tags: visas, sweden

I have an interview invitation in one of the companies in Sweden, however, the visa submission is just 8 days before the invitation date. And based on the visa website, it takes around 15 days for result of the visa application. Thus the invitation date might pass before I get the visa result. Will my visa be denied? Do I need to update the invitation dates and the insurance coverage? The company however can change the dates, but I have already submitted the application.